# Stability of VAR(1)

Tags: time-series, self-study, references, stationarity, vector-autoregression

Consider VAR(1) process 
$$y_t = A_1y_{t-1} + u_t.$$

I am looking for a reference or proof that if all entries in $A_1$ are less than one in modulus then $y_t$ is stable. I am sure that last semester a professor told that, but I can't find a reference.

---

**Edit1:**
In response to @Jarle Tufto answer, I believe that this is a sufficient condition. To support my argument I did a simulation in `R` where I simulate 20 different series (100 steps ahead) for the case when entries in $A_1$ are uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$. All series converge to zero.

[image]

The `R` code

```
n <- 20 #fix the number of series
I = diag(n)
A <- matrix(runif(n^2), ncol = n, nrow = n) #Create matrix A with 0 < a_ij < 1
y = matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = 100) #create vector of predictions (100 steps ahead)
y[, 1] = rnorm(n) #set initial values
for (i in 2:ncol(y)) {
    y[, i] = A^(i-1)%*%y[, i-1]
}
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
y_m <- melt(y)
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = y_m, aes(x = X2, y = value, color = factor(X1))) + 
  xlab('Step') + ylab('Value')
```

**Edit 2:**

Here is the result for the case when all entries of $A$ are $0.9$. In the previous code I changed

`A <- matrix(runif(n^2), ncol = n, nrow = n)`

to

`A <- matrix(0.9, ncol = n, nrow = n)`

Still have convergence, though the shape looks strange.

[image]

Comment: VAR is an acronym, so there is no need to format it as a formula. Good question, though.

Comment: That was just good (or maybe bad) luck. It is not a sufficient condition.  Try $A$ with all entries equal to .9 and it will not be stationary!

Comment: @JarleTufto please see my second edit.

Comment: I don't understand your simulation code.  Inside your for-loop you do 'y[, i] = A^(i-1)%*%y[, i-1]'.  Why do you raise all elements of A to the $(i-1)$ power?  And you need to add the white noise term $u_t$.

Comment: @JarleTufto oops, agree. Indeed, you are right, this is not a sufficient condition. Forgot that `^` should be replaced by `%^%` in `R` (with loading `expm` package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VAR(1) process is stationary if the largest eigenvalue of $A$ has modulus smaller than 1, see [Wei 2006, ch. 16](https://www.google.no/search?q=wei%20time%20series%20analysis&oq=wei%20time%20series).  The condition you refer to is neither a necessary or sufficient condition for stationarity.

Answer (score 0):

I think your simulations are just luck. Take this example:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.8 & 0.2 \\
0.4 & 0.6
\end{bmatrix}
$$

All entries are less than 1 but the matrix has 1 as an eigenvalue. So it is not stationary. Any starting point other than (0,0) that is less than one in the two entries will eventually converge to (2/3 , 1/3). And if they are higher than 1, it will diverge.

Take a look at the definition of markov matrices.